# How do I install older version of protobuf?

Tags: homebrew, protocol-buffers

I need to install protobuf 2.6.1

brew install  protobuf gives me 3.1.0, the current version

How do I install protobuf 2.6.1 on Mac?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/2383721) to see if any of these techniques will get you the version you want? If not, you could install it from [the git repo](https://github.com/google/protobuf) with tag `v2.6.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Someone maintains versioned recipes for home brew, you can use this:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulirish/homebrew-versions-1/master/protobuf260.rb
```

Comment: The recipe appears to be out of date. I get a 404 when it attempts to download at `https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/protobuf260-2.6.0.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz`